# Recognize equal signs as text in EXCEL cells

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying in EXCEL to count the number of equal signs present in a range of cells. They are just text to me. I am using the EXCEL function COUNTIF(), but it seems that EXCEL always recognize the equal signs as a formula. Thsi is the formula I am typing:  `=COUNTIF(A1:M1;"=")`. I also tried an apostrophe before the equal sign , but it seems not to work neither.

```
=COUNTIF(A1:M1;"=")
```

I expect to obtain in a cell the number of equal signs in  a given range of cells

Comment: Have you formatted cells as text yet?

Comment: You've got two good answers, but I'm not sure which one you want - e.g. if your had two cells containing "=" and "==", would the answer be two or three?

Comment: What is the C# tie in to this question?  Are you looking for a C# solution?  If not, what about a UDF?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by substituting out the char, measuring the string length before and after the substitution, see [this article at ExcelJet](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-specific-characters-in-a-range).

Try

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A1:M1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:M1,"=","")))
```

Comment: it's a clever way to do it, but I'm having a hard time believing there is no better way. Since with this method each cell-value has to be checked 3 times... (1.OriginalLength, 2.Replace, 3.NewLength) whereas what you want just should be (1. Iterate and count occurances).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this COUNTIF function.

```
=COUNTIF(A1:M1,"*=*")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this solves my problem perfectly.

Comment: I'm glad my suggestion found your approval. Meanwhile, some smart "expert" stuck a down-vote on it. Please do me a favour and "select" my answer. Thank you.

Comment: This is the best answer, i came here and found what i wanted!. some "idiot" voted down the question and answer. i counter acted to reset to 0. hope this helps. DirkCruz please accept this answer. @Variatus Thank you.